# Snow Leopard custom script on startup?

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, boot, connection-sharing

I'm sharing my MacBook's internet connection wirelessly with a PC, and every time I startup my Mac, I need to go to System Preferences>Sharing and uncheck then recheck the Internet Sharing box again just to re-activate the internet sharing because I don't know why my MacBook isn't sharing the connection at startup since the box is already checked.

That's why I'm looking for a way to automate this action at startup so I don't have to keep repeating doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way to do it is to use Automator and record your screen actions. Then run the workflow at startup.